# Bootstrap slider with row content issues

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s1.postimg.org/ndn5u1rf3/home_slider1.jpg one');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s1.postimg.org/6sk4s4pov/home_slider2.jpg two');"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s1.postimg.org/uktg3nrpr/home_slider3.jpg three');"></div>
     </div>
       <div class="item">
      <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://s1.postimg.org/uschmfdan/home_slider4.jpg four');"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
     </header>
    <!--Row with three equal columns-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--Column left-->
        <img src="img/logo_new.png" style="width:146px; heigt:82px;" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4"><!--Column middle-->
        <h1>Live Safely with AlertID </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <!--Column right-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now it shows, like [this](http://s4.postimg.org/dk6tr23yl/untitled.gif)

I need to add above row content on the top of the slider.

Sample site http://alertid.com/default_v5.asp

May i know how to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to either

1. add a new row to your table layout (probably best since your entire layout is a table)
2. Or add something like a bootstrap nav(less effort)

Here how to add a new row...

```html
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="tblmain">
       <!--your current code stops.....-->
      <tr><td><!---your new content here--></td></tr>
      
      <tr><!--your current code continues.....-->
```

..and heres a bootstrap Well, you can add a bit of css to suit your needs.

```html
<!-- insert after body opening tag -->
<div class="well">content to go here</div>
```

Comment: nope.. i don't want use table, I need to work with bootstrap classes.. thanks

Comment: @saina updated the answer with a navbar example. One question if you only want bootstrap classes why is your site structure in a table?

Comment: Navbar using when we use menus right?.. Here why you use navbar

Comment: Wait do you want to add a row ontop of your slider or "on the top of your slider"? If its ontop, then simply swap out the navbar  for a welli.e <div class="well">

Comment: on the top of my slider... did you see my sample site? thanks

Comment: Yes, answer updated for a well, if you dont want the default style instead of the class of well give it the class "col-md-12".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88874/discussion-between-saina-and-kurt).